# Selenium IE web-driver stopped working after specific interval of time

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I'm using Selenium web-driver version 2.53 and Internet Explorer version 11. I noticed that after some time of execution of web-driver, it getting crashed frequently and I need to restart web-driver again and again. Please help on this problem.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting when it crashed???

Comment: browser server may have died exception

Answer (score 0):

Go to **IE11 --> Internet Options --> Security --> Change security level to Medium-high zones** (i.e. Internet, Local intranet and Trusted sites).

And Check Enable Protected Mode for all the Zones